# Hanging lamp attached to a cord animation

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I am trying to make an animation showing a hanging lamp attached to a cord.
I am quite at the beginning regarding to physics (and blender in generell).

So I made a cord, put the cloth simulation on, pinned the top few verticies and put some smooth wind on it. Now I want the the lamp to move with the hanging cable. How  can I do that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your setup to visualize what you are trying to do? A simulation seems overkill, maybe a generated sinus/noise would be enough, depending on the exact situation.

Comment: Here is the setup, you mean the noise modifier in the graph editor, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Object Constraints:

Add a new vertex group to the cord, and add the bottom vertex to it. Add a "Child Of" object constraint to the lamp, select the cord as target and the new vertex group as Vertex Group. Then position your lamp so it sits under the cord. The lamp now moves with the bottom vertex of the cord.

**Result:**

[image: result]

Comment: It seems to work, thank you! 
The only thing that is still off is that the cord and the lightbulb are not really aligned when the wind appears. (They are perfectly alligned at the beginning).

I put a photo in my question post.